# Magento 2: Set Custom product attribute value programmatically on product save

Tags: magento2, product, custom-attributes

How to set a product's custom attribute on save?
I have used the event/observer way but nothing works.

Answer (score 25):

### Official method should work, but Not

The official method `setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $attributeValue)` below should work but **NOT** because the **official bug** https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4703.

The bug doesn't fix yet in version 2.2.3.

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$product->setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

### Temporary method

After many debug and tries, I found the method `$product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue)` below could set custom attribute successfully, it is a temporary method.

Hope it could help you. Any better way is welcome to post :)

```
private $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function updateProductAttribute($productId)
{
    $attributeCode = "Attribute_code";
    $attributeValue = "Attribute Value Here";
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    //$product->setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
    $product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
    $this->productRepository->save($product);
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me using Magento 2.3.0. The only way I was able to get it was `$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, $attributeValue);` Very frustrating lol

Answer (score 2):

Rather using the setcustomattribute function you can just use this:
Suppose your attribute code is inbound.

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$product->setInbound($attributeValue);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Answer (score 2):

The most upvoted answer didn't work for me on Magento 2.3.5 while creating a new product programatically.

Most probably because it depends on the type of custom attribute. If it's a dropdown or swatch, then you need to set the option ID, not the value.

So this is the method I ended up using (for the color attribute):

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$color = 'Black';
$product_resource = $product->getResource();
$color_attribute = $product_resource->getAttribute('color');
if ($color_attribute->usesSource()) {
    $color_option_id = $color_attribute->getSource()->getOptionId($color);
    if ($color_option_id != '') {
        $product->setData('color', $color_option_id);
    }
}       
... // set other attributes 
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use event observer `catalog_product_save_before` to avoid loading and saving product separately extra time.

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$product = $observer->getData('product');
$product->setData('my_attribute', 'Some value');
```

Or plugin `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product::beforeSave`, because indexers already declare plugins on this method (for example, \Magento\CatalogRule\Plugin\Indexer\Product\Save\ApplyRules::afterSave);

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2.3.2
"Save" method of calss "Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" not worked for me. Gives "Unique constraint violation found error".
[image]

Method "updateAttributes" of class "Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action" worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
namespace vendor\module\Observer;

class ProductSaveAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->productFactroy = $productFactory;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $user = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
        $productId = (int) $observer->getProduct()->getId();
        $product = $this->productFactroy->create()->load($productId);
        $product->addAttributeUpdate("updated_by", $user, 0);//attribute,value,storeid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

            $prod = $product->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
$prod->setCustomattribute($value); // name of your custom attribute
$prod->save();
```

Comment: got this error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`)

Comment: i used the  `catalog_product_save_after` event/observer method for this

Comment: please add code here

Comment: check link 

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192201/magento-2-set-product-attribute-dynamically

Comment: i posted a new question