# Magento 2: Set Product Attribute Dynamically

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

How to set product attribute dynamically, I am using `catalog_product_save_after` event and catch the event using Observer.

here is my observer

```
<?php

namespace Learning\HelloPage\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    

    protected $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $admin_user_id = $this->authSession->getUser()->getId();
        $_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $_product->setAdminUserId('2');
        // $_product->setData('admin_user_id', '2');

    }       
}
```

here is my events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="product_observer" instance="Learning\HelloPage\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and i got this error on product save.

[image]

here is my custom attribute that is updated on product save.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get price and after updating then try to set it.
    e.g

```
public function updateWholeSalePrice($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $_product->getPrice();   
    $_product->getWholesaleprice(); 
    $wholesalePrice = (float)(($_product->getPrice())*5)/100;
    $product->setWholesaleprice($wholesalePrice);
}
```

see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/24032241