# Need to save custom attribute during product save grammatically in magneto 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I have custom attribute in form of drop down and multiselect.But during product save these are not saving in database like i have a warranty dropdown attribute.

```
 $product->setwarranty($wholedata['product']['warranty']); // Product Warranty
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way:**

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

**Reference:**

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/229280/75828