# How to add colour attribute value for product when creating programatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am creating a product programmatically. There is a custom colour attribute. I want to add the value for attribute and save it for product.

```
$product->setColor('White'); // color attribute
```

[image]

Comment: Hope , it helps you [enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192160/magento-2-set-custom-product-attribute-value-programmatically-on-product-save/192186)

Comment: Please check this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192160/magento-2-set-custom-product-attribute-value-programmatically-on-product-save/192186