# Set custom attribute value for a product programatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, custom, import

I have created custom attributes for a product. I am doing product import programmatically.
How to set value for the custom attributes programmatically in magento 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2: Set Custom product attribute value programmatically on product save](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192160/magento-2-set-custom-product-attribute-value-programmatically-on-product-save)

Comment: There is no proper solution there. None of the solution is marked accepted.