# how to set product attribute value programmatically magento2

Tags: magento2

I've made a product attribute "inbound" and it has two options, yes and no, I have assigned "no" to it initially but when I'm checking out I'm using an observer to change its value to "yes" programmatically if product quantity less then 100, everything is working fine but can't able to change its value to yes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the code where you are setting the attribute value.

Comment: i just want to know how to set attribute value programatically,cant show the code bt ihave tried  " setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $attributeValue) " function using Magento\Framework\Api\CustomAttributesDataInterface dependency its giving error

Comment: Please refer this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192160/magento-2-set-custom-product-attribute-value-programmatically-on-product-save 2> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Unable-to-update-custom-product-attribute-value-programatically/td-p/112739

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can set attribute value

`$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
$this->productRepository->save($product);`

Comment: you are using $this->productRepository->getById($productId); so it means i can use  Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository dependency ??

Comment: Yes you can set product attribute , by loading product's object and then use set method to set attribute value and then save.

Comment: Try and let us know if its helpful and works , give upvote on the answer if it works 4 you, so it will help to others in Magento community.

Comment: Worked or not ?

Comment: hey there,  my attribute is multiselect and its adding a new row for the attribute.if a product already has a attribute value selected like "no" if i tried to make it "yes" using your code its working but its not eliminating the "no" it sets both values yes and no for the product

Comment: is there any posibility to unset no and set yes to the attribute??

Comment: i've checked it by making selectbox and multiselect both its adding a new row to attribute which is making a mismatch in data in db.you can refer to this image below.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rxuu76

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the answers, it really helps, i got the right way to do that,
 rather using setcustomasttribute function cause its throwing errors.you can just simply do this.

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$product->setInbound($attributeValue);
$product->setData('store_id', 0);//remember to set store id other wwise data 
mismatch occurs//
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```